# iOS Watch Simulator size becomes Large

Tags: size, ios-simulator, watchkit

I encounter something weird today.

Been using watch app sim with scale 100% all the while. And the size is small as one would expect for a watch.

But today, I terminated the watch sim, and rerun the app and suddenly the size has become larger. Like almost the size of iPhone6S simulator at 50% scale.

Here is a picture.
[image]

Question is this normal? How can I get back the original size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Simulator, sometimes scale does get reset.

Shortcut to scale up and down is press **command + 1 or command + 2 or command + 3**. It will scale it properly.

You can check with Windows -> Scale.

Comment: Seems like a bug. When I see Scale menu, there is none being ticked. Ticking to 100% returns it to normal size again. Actually it is better to be bigger size too (easier to see). Wish apple add 200% for watch sim scale.

Comment: Yes, this does seem like a bug to me.  It hasn't been reported before, so file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com if you can figure out reproduction steps.